# Bootstrap dropdown menu as include file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm in the process of creating my first dynamic site using bootstrap and have set up a nav-list with drop down submenu as a separate include file. It works on the index page, but when I navigate to any other page the drop down stops working on the new page. What am I doing wrong?
This is the line of code added to all pages

```
<?php include 'libs/nav.php'; ?>
```

and the nav.php file has the following code

```
<ul class="nav nav-list well">
<li class="active"><a data-target="" data-toggle="pill" href="")">HOME</a></li>
<li class="nav-header">Product Categories</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cameras <i class="icon-expand-alt"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="category-1">35mm</a></li>
        <li><a href="category-57">Digital</a></li>          
        <li><a href="category-31">Medium-Format</a></li>
        <li><a href="category-18">Instant</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: what is not working? are you including bootstrap css and js files in all pages?

Comment: Yes I believe everything is in the correct place. The dropdown sub menu appear when I click on the main menu item when I'm on the home page, but when I go to the dynamic page ie category-1 the menu is included as expected, but the drop downs no longer work

Comment: have you checked for any errors in console? Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome

Comment: I'm using firefox and all errors are bootstrap CSS related

Comment: Any ideas anyone? I'm using standard js files. Do I need to amend those to make this kind of menu work?

Comment: can you link us to your site?

Comment: it's on local at the moment. So I've placed it here http://project3101.com/ as you can see some of the menu items are working but not others. The top menu doesn't work either but that's less important right now

Comment: While you're looking perhaps you can answer why the top menu has the correct href, but will only open if I right click and open in a new tab? I'm at a beginner stage of learning

Comment: Couple things to try: make sure all your links in the menu have the attribute `href="#"`, remove the `li` with class `dropdown-menu` that class should just go in the ul, you're including both the normal and minified version of boostrap.js, you should only use one. For your top menu, remove the attr `data-toggle="tab"` since you're not using tab content and finally, I noticed you have a `div#wrap` in your markup before the `<!DOCTYPE html>` you should remove it as it invalid markup

Comment: thanks for your help - few questions. If I set href="#" how do I get the links to go to pages such as href="category-1"? Removing li class drop down menu stops the drop down working. Removing bootstrap.min.js appears to have fixed the issue with menu not working on all other pages. It now does work, but no longer on the index page? data-toggle="tab" fixed the top menu, thanks. Sorted the div wrap issue, thanks also. Getting closer

Comment: Ah found why the index page isn't working. I had copied the bootstrap carousel script onto the page and it had the call for jQuery 1.9, and bootstrap.js. Removing that has fixed that issue so it all seems to work. You're a star!

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted everything out. And yes I meant the links that toggle dropdowns should have `href="#"` sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You should just have include 'nameoffile.php' where you want the include code to be displayed.

Are all files in the same folder location? If so there's no reason for the above to not work

Comment: Thanks Steve yes I have done that. And the files are in the same folder location. I think it's something to do with dropdown-toggle or data-toggle as other parts of the same menu without drop downs work on all pages. That indicates that the menu is set up correctly and files are in the correct place. I'm working on local could that cause the error?

Comment: As a test you can duplicate the page thy its working on and rename it. See if I works just as a test case.

Comment: so duplicate index.php as index-copy.php, change <li><a href="category-1">35mm</a></li> on nav.php to li><a href="index-copy.php">index-copy</a></li> and then click on the link and the menu works correctly on both pages, but if I then go to my dynamic page ( category.php ) called from the menu as category-x the drop down doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and it was being cause by the order in which I implemented the scripts. Make sure your jquery script is above the bootstrap script.

```
<link href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="libs/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```